# How do I attach my application into Share?

Tags: android, kotlin, share, external, internals

i want to attach my app into "Share" when user select a img,mp4 or pdf to share.

As shown below. How do I do that ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `intent-filter` to your activity. There is quite some stuff to understand, so I suggest you look into [this resource](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive).